# CSS: truncate text without stretching an element?

Tags: css

I have this calendar:

[image]

And this CSS class:

```
.fc-special-day {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 90%;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Using this class truncate thing works, but what it does, it stretches the element as you can see in screenshot, `March 11` element causes whole column to be stretched out.

What I want is to just truncate text if there is no space left to write respecting original element width (as you can see other columns are not stretched, so thats the original width). . If I remove `white-space: nowrap;`, then text goes in multiple lines.

Also if I change `width` to be let say `px`, then it only works on some specific `zoom`. If I zoom out or zoom in, then it either truncates too early or too soon (meaning there will be more space left then there needs to or it goes over number that represents day).

Comment: Did you tried to use span and set it's width to be a percent of the div ?Like that it can't go multiple lines and can't overflow the div

Comment: @O.Rares I did not.

Comment: I used a similar with that in the past and worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `O.Rares` suggested, I was able to truncate text without stretching an element by using `span`. Here is the version I was able to do it if someone will need it:

```
.fc-special-day {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 88%;
}
.fc-special-day > span {
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[image]